# Get URI or ID for Media from RELATIVE_PATH + DISPLAY_NAME

Tags: android, kotlin, scoped-storage

I'm trying to simply add Audio Files. My solution mostly works. But where it does  not work is when the file already exists in the `MediaStore`. The once I've looked at more closely also **only** exist in the `MediaStore` there is no file on the device at the location.

```
val values = ContentValues().apply {
   put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, libraryPart.rootFolderRelativePath) // JDrop/1/1
   put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, remoteLibraryEntry.getFilename()) //12.mp3
   put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_PENDING, 1)
   if(mimeType != null)
       put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, mimeType) // audio/mpeg3
}

val collection = MediaStore.Audio.Media
       .getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)

var uri = ctx.contentResolver.insert(collection, values) // returns null for around 300/2000 files consistently
```

Logcat outputs the following when trying to insert that new file.

```
2020-01-24 22:27:33.724 4015-7707/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting title_key= bucket_display_name=1 owner_package_name=shio.at.jdrop parent=79657 volume_name=external_primary title_resource_uri=null _display_name=12.mp3 mime_type=audio/mpeg3 _data=/storage/emulated/0/Music/JDrop/1/1/12.mp3 title= group_id=1569 artist_id=322 is_pending=1 date_added=1579901253 album_id=2958 primary_directory=Music secondary_directory=JDrop bucket_id=687581593 media_type=2 relative_path=Music/JDrop/1/1/ from {P:30220;U:10165}
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: files._data (code 2067 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:879)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:790)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:88)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1639)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1494)
    at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.insertFile(MediaProvider.java:3050)
    at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.insertInternal(MediaProvider.java:3452)
    at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.insert(MediaProvider.java:3240)
    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:325)
    at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:164)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1032)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1005)
```

So `files._data` would mean the file already exists in the `MediaStore`. There is no file at `JDrop/1/1/12.mp3`, it's just in the `MediaStore` and I need to somehow get rid of it or get an OutputStream for the existing `MediaStore` entry and update it accordingly.

I've tried to query for the `ID` in the `MediaStore` without success using the following code. Either finding out the `ID` or the `URI` would be fine. Furthermore `MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA` is deprecated as of SDK 29. So I would like to query it without using that.

```
if(uri == null) {
    val id: Long = ctx.contentResolver.query(
            collection,
            arrayOf(BaseColumns._ID),
            "${MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH}=? AND ${MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME}=?",
            arrayOf(libraryPart.rootFolderRelativePath, remoteLibraryEntry.getFilename()),
            null)?.use {
        if (it.moveToNext())
            it.getLong(it.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID))
        else null
    } ?: return false

    uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id!!.toString())
}
```

## EDIT 1 (Querying _data)

I also now tried to query against `_data` with the hardcoded path that I know I cannot insert, without much success.

```
val id: Long = ctx.contentResolver.query(
            collection,
            arrayOf(BaseColumns._ID),
            "${MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA}=?",
            arrayOf("/storage/emulated/0/Music/JDrop/1/1/12.mp3"),
            null)?.use {
        if (it.moveToNext())
            it.getLong(it.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID))
        else null
    } ?: return false
```

Also gets back null and returns false.

## EDIT 2 (Querying everything and see what it returns)

I tried to do a little test query against the entier collection as suggested.

```
class TestQueryObject(val id: Long, val relativePath: String, val displayName: String)
val results = mutableListOf<TestQueryObject>()

ctx.contentResolver.query(
        collection,
        arrayOf(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME),
        null,
        null,
        null)?.use {
    while (it.moveToNext()) {
        results.add(TestQueryObject(
                id = it.getLong(it.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID)),
                relativePath = it.getString(it.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH)),
                displayName = it.getString(it.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME))
        ))
    }
}

var find12 = results.find { it.displayName == "12.mp3" }
```

It returns a list of 2557 entries. As an example for the first one the name is `"5.mp3"` the id is `79658` the relative path is `"Music/JDrop/1/1"`. There is a `Music/` in front of it that I did not know of. But find12 is still null.

## EDIT 3 (Additional thoughts that may or may not be important)

It might also be worth noting that it does not happen on an Android emulator that I created with android 10. But it does on my OnePlus 6 with around those 300'ish files and works for all the rest. I already was using the Program with Android 9 and then upgraded to Android 10. I've read somewhere that files from Android 9 when you upgrade to 10 might be considered orphaned as opposed to belonging to your appllication (at least that is what happens when you uninstall the app that created them). So I may just no longer have access to the mediastore entries I'm looking for? However, i also thought. reading media is accessable to any app now without ANY permission. So if it's an access problem it should fail when trying to write to it. Not when reading or finding it.

Furthermore as @CommonsWare mentioned `IS_PENDING` may still be set to `1`. I do set it back to `0` in the code below what I posted. However, that code may never be executed whenever I close the program while debugging as 9/10 times it's going to be at the part where it downloads and writes the file as that takes **by far** the longest time of anything happening in the program.

Comment: You are missing `AND` between the two halves of your `WHERE` clause, and you are missing one element in your `WHERE` arguments array.

Comment: Oh yeah you are right. But I believe this was an error in drafting this question. I'm gonna double check and edit the question afterwards. Earlier I tried to query just with the RELATIVE_PATH and not the name to see if it returns anything at all there and it did not.

Comment: I edited that now. Sorry for the posting mistake.

Comment: I assume you eventually set `IS_PENDING` to `0`, otherwise that may be part of your problem. If that's not it, you might try running a scrap `query()` for all items and see what gets returned for `RELATIVE_PATH` and `DISPLAY_NAME` for your item (finding it by eyeball in the returned list). It is possible that your values get normalized or something by `MediaStore`, so the values that you put in are not identical to the values that you would need to query against.

Comment: Yes, I do that. But it may still be the case when I randomly stop debugging. Since downloading a FLAC (worst case) takes way longer than doing all the rest this program is supposed to do. 9/10 times I stop the program while debugging it probably did not set the PENDING back to 0 for that file. If you're wondering what the program is doing it's syncing my music library from JRiver Media Center to my phone over http from my NAS. A little project I'm working on every now and then. Obviously, as you can see it broke with Android Q.

I'm gonna try to run that scrap query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the problem now. Thank's @CommonsWare to mention the pending bit. It might have taken me **much longer** to figure it out.

There is an method `Uri MediaStore.setIncludePending(Uri uri)` that you give your uri in and you get an uri back with witch you can query with the pending items included.

Using this new Uri I got from this method returns my `find12` thing successfully!

```
val collection = MediaStore.Audio.Media
    .getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
        
var uri = ctx.contentResolver.insert(collection, values)

if(uri == null) {

    class TestQueryObject(val id: Long, val relativePath: String, val displayName: String)
    val results = mutableListOf<TestQueryObject>()

    ctx.contentResolver.query(
            MediaStore.setIncludePending(collection),
            arrayOf(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME),
            null,
            null,
            null)?.use {
        while (it.moveToNext()) {
            results.add(TestQueryObject(
                    id = it.getLong(it.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID)),
                    relativePath = it.getString(it.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH)),
                    displayName = it.getString(it.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME))
            ))
        }
    }

    var find12 = results.find { it.displayName == "12.mp3" }
}
```

Now I can start to make this actually work again.

---

Edit Android11

It appears on Android11 `MediaStore.setIncludePending(collection)` is now deprecated and we are instead supposed to [use a different query method that accepts a bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#query(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.CancellationSignal)).

So it becomes something like this

```kotlin
val queryCollection =
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
            MediaStore.setIncludePending(collection)
        else collection

val queryProjection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID)

val querySelection = "${MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH}=? AND ${MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME}=?"
val querySelectionArgs = arrayOf("someRelativePath", "someFilename")

val queryBundle = Bundle().apply {
    putString(ContentResolver.QUERY_ARG_SQL_SELECTION, querySelection)
    putStringArray(ContentResolver.QUERY_ARG_SQL_SELECTION_ARGS, querySelectionArgs)
}

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
     queryBundle.putInt(MediaStore.QUERY_ARG_MATCH_PENDING, MediaStore.MATCH_INCLUDE)

ctx.contentResolver.query(queryCollection, queryProjection, queryBundle, null)?.use {
    ... Do something
}
```

Those variables to include the pending items in the bundle are not available prior to android 11.

It might be a better idea to just enable legacy storage for android 10 support and tread it like android < 10 and only implement scoped storage on android 10. The option is ignored on android 11, but still works if the app the runs on android 10.

Comment: so how can i get the uri of that file after getting id?

Comment: Something like this should work ```Uri.withAppendedPath(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id)```

Comment: i tired that but when i want to openOutputStream on that uri, i get FileNotFoundException

Comment: I was having the exact same problem (stopping in the middle of an insert operation) and haven't set IS_PENDING back to 0.... I was trying several ways to inject SQL into the ContentResolver query, after finding this answer, I realized there is MediaStore.setIncludePending() exactly for that.